# Is VBA able to store each array individually and wait to print them to a template?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is there a way to have this script form the entire array based off the rows I want it to extract based on the `IF Statement`?

I know this finds a name on the `Mgrs` worksheet, and finds those rows in the `Data` worksheet, but then it directly prints it after forming the array. Can I have this code store all of the data, and then wait to print the data on a template that I format myself?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CIB_Cuts()
Dim j As Long, k As Long, x As Long
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim varArray2() As Variant
ReDim varArray(1 To 19, 1 To 1)

Dim strManager As String, strEC As String, strLogin As String
Dim BASEPATH As String, strNewPath As String, strFileName As String
Dim Wb As Workbook

Dim mgrRow As Long
Dim colManager As Long
colManager = 3
Dim colLogin As Long
colLogin = 4
Dim colEC As Long
colEC = 5

BASEPATH = "M:\Final Files\"

Call speedupcode(True)

For mgrRow = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mgrs").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mgrs").Cells(mgrRow, 3) <> "" Then
        strManager = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mgrs").Cells(mgrRow, 3)

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
            ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)
            x = 1
            For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                varArray(k, x) = .Cells(1, k)
            Next
            For j = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                If strManager = .Cells(j, colManager) Then
                    x = x + 1
                    ReDim Preserve varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To x)
                    For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                        If k = 1 Then
                            varArray(1, x) = CStr(Format(.Cells(j, k), "000000000"))
                        Else
                            varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
                        End If
                        strEC = .Cells(j, colEC)
                        strManager = .Cells(j, colManager)
                        strLogin = .Cells(j, colLogin)
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End With

                    strFileName = strLogin & " - " & strManager & " - " & "Shift Differential Validation" & ".xlsx"

        ReDim varArray2(1 To UBound(varArray, 2), 1 To UBound(varArray, 1))

        Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
        With Wb
            With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
                .Columns(15).NumberFormat = "0%"

                For j = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
                    For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                        varArray2(j, k) = varArray(k, j)
                    Next
                Next

                .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2

                    Call DataValidation
                    Call Header

                    .Range("C2").Select
                     ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

                    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                    .Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True

                    Call protect

           End With

            .SaveAs strNewPath & strFileName, Password:="password", FileFormat:=51
            .Saved = True
            .Close

        End With
        Set Wb = Nothing
    End If
Next

Call speedupcode(False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the array each time in an overarching array or a collection and loop that at the end...

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim varArray2() As Variant, results As Collection
    'other code..
    Set results = New Collection

    results.Add varArray2
End Sub
```

You could also use `Select Case` , or something distinctive during the loop, to determine a key and populate a dictionary with the arrays as values which might make retrieval of specific items easier.

Comment: do you think this would be more efficient than how I have it printing to a new workbook every time my varArray has collected the first round of data?

Comment: depends. Does it need to go to a new workbook each time? I guess, if it does and you know when, within the collection, you switch to new workbook writeout not sure huge difference. May be faster with initial method.   Try both and see.

Comment: I would like to print these to a template, and I know that would quicken things. I could easily just store everything, separately, into  a bunch of arrays within an array, and then print & save copy of template. The only problem being that the SaveCopyAs function doesn't allow password protecting.

Comment: also, I already have a varArray 2, would I need to make a 3rd array variant, or edit my pre-existing varArray 2?